# I already have an add function how can I use it in multiplication function?

Tags: haskell

So far I have the definitions for n-1 and n+1 with suc and inc respectively

```
add x y | y > 0 = add (inc x) (suc y)
add x y | y < 0 = add (suc x) (inc y)
add x 0 = x
add 0 y = y
```

How can I use this in my multiplication function using only recursion, if-then and no +, -, etc

I know that the result of x * y is equal to adding y to the result of (x-1) * y

But I just don't know how I can put it into the code. Thanks.

Comment: You don't say what functions are denoted by `inc` and `suc`, they're not standard Haskell. From the context, it is clear that `inc x` must be `x + 1` and `suc x` = `x - 1`. I would suggest to call that last function `pred` (predecessor) rather than `suc` which suggests "successor"  (like the function `succ` from the Standard Prelude)

Comment: What have you tried? You should post your own attempts to show some effort before asking people to hand you a solution to your exercise / homework.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework and the OP hasn't posted any attempt.

Comment: Seconding the homework closed; This is a follow up to a question the op posted yesterday and in both cases there was clearly no effort on the ops side involved.

Answer (score 3):

If we define the natural numbers as:

```hs
data Nat where
    Zero :: Nat        -- 0
    Succ :: Nat -> Nat -- \n -> n + 1
```

Then, we can define `add` as follows:

```hs
add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add n Zero     = n              -- n + 0 = n
add n (Succ m) = Succ (add n m) -- n + (m + 1) = (n + m) + 1
```

Next, we can define `mul` in terms of `add`:

```hs
mul :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mul n Zero     = Zero            -- n * 0 = 0
mul n (Succ m) = add (mul n m) n -- n * (m + 1) = (n * m) + n
```

Similarly, we can define `exp` in terms of `mul`:

```
exp :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
exp n Zero     = Succ Zero       -- n ^ 0 = 1
exp n (Succ m) = mul (exp n m) n -- n ^ (m + 1) = (n ^ m) * n
```

Notice a pattern here? This is known as [primitive recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function).

Comment: what about `exp Zero Zero` :)?

Comment: @JakubDaniel Anything raised to zero is one.

Comment: Except `0`. See [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0^0). But I understand why it is not such a big deal, but still.

Answer (score 0):

The basic implementation is:

```
mul x 0 = 0
mul x y = add x (mul x (y - 1))
```

you would need to replace `y - 1` with your decrement function (which is oddly named `suc`). Also this does not work for negative multipliers, but you can play with it.